# Передача значения переменной JavaScript в PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Нужна помощь касательно перевода переменной из JavaScript в PHP.
У меня есть вот такой код JS:

http://pastie.org/8936171

Из него мне необходимо передать значение в PHP

```
this.scoreContainer   = document.querySelector(".score-container");
```

Comment: Так JScript или JavaScript?

Comment: @LightShock JavaScript.

Comment: а в чем проблема ? ну сделайте метод типа sendScore(). который `this.scoreContainer[0].innerHTML` (или перебором все) будет послать с помощью ajax.

Comment: @eicto Я не имел дела с Ajax...(

Comment: @VLADPRO100LORD ну так научитесь. масса туториалов и док.

Answer (score 0):

```
var request = XMLHttpRequest();
request.withCredentials = true;

request.open('POST', 'name_of_php_script.php', true);

// если отправляем json
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
// иначе
request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

request.send(JSON.stringify({data: document.querySelector(".score-container").innerText}));

request.onload = function(){
  if(request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
    // обрабатываем ответ сервера
  } else {
    throw new Error(request.status + ' (' + request.statusText + ')');
  }
}
```

// name_of_php_script.php

```
if(isset($_POST('data'))){
  // делаем что то с переданными данными.
}
```